# Force a panel to be square in wx (python)

Tags: python, wxpython, panel, wxwidgets

Does anybody know how i would go about forcing a panel to be square.

The case where this occurs is have a panel in which I have a horizontal BoxSizer with 2 slots, In the left slot i have a panel that I am going to be drawing to though wx.PaintDC, on the right I am going to have a a list control or some other widget.

What i am trying to achieve is to have the window realizable and to have the left panel always stay square, and to have the right hand content fill the rest of the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solutions is to use EVT_SIZE to respond to window resizing and update panel size in the event function. Simple example code:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.mixins.inspection import InspectionMixin

class MyApp(wx.App, InspectionMixin):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.Init()  # initialize the inspection tool
        frame = wx.Frame(None)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        frame.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.__squarePanel = wx.Panel(frame)
        sizer.Add(self.__squarePanel, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        frame.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)

        frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True  

    def OnSize(self, evt):
        frame = evt.GetEventObject()
        frameW, frameH = frame.GetSize()
        targetSide = min(frameW, frameH)
        self.__squarePanel.SetSize((targetSide, targetSide))


app = MyApp()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This is a pretty god answer and is working on the most part except the right hand pane is not resizing automatically with the left pane sliding under elements, I will have a go at resizing the right panel in the same event, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I have decided to go a different route, as you provided a good starting point to go from I am marking yours the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to `wx.EVT_SIZE` to resize the panel when the window is resized. Partial code (untested, but someting like this):

```
self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(200, 200))
self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.resize_panel)

def resize_panel():
    w, h = self.sizer.GetSize()
    w = h
    panel.SetSize(w, h)
```